# Using python, how do I copy a folder (and all of its contents) to clipboard?

Tags: python, directory, clipboard

I would like to create a program that looks through every file in a folder tree, grabs every file with the extension ".py", and then copies a new folder containing only the .py files to the clipboard.

As far as I'm aware, the code would have to look something like this:

```
import os, shutil

os.makedirs("All .py files")

for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            shutil.copy(filename, "All .py files")

# CODE TO COPY "ALL .PY FILES" FOLDER TO CLIPBOARD
```

What fill-in-the-blank code would work here?

The simpler the answer, the more appreciative I would be :) I'm very new to python and don't know that much yet!

Comment: what do you mean by clipboard? The place where files get stored when you do `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Yes, where files get stored when you press ctrl+C